# Compare editor in Eclipse Juno and blank save dialog

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse Juno with PDT plugin on Windows Vista. The problem is during to try to save a file in compare editor. All changes are display fine, copy of changes works good, but when i try to save a file (shotcut ctrl+s or save icon) a get an empty dialog with two buttons (yes and no).

If i click Yes then it looks like really saved but if i reopen file then i see no changes there.

Any idea what is the reason of this problem?

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=330672 , https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385261